# How to access graph after re-login on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

Unable to access graph after re-login.

I created new graph named "graph" and access my graph.
But, Unable to access my graph after re-login.

```
$ agens
agens (AgensGraph 2.1.0, based on PostgreSQL 10.4)
Type "help" for help.

agens=# create graph graph;
CREATE GRAPH
agens=# match (n) return n;
 n 
---
(0 rows)

agens=# \quit
$ agens
agens (AgensGraph 2.1.0, based on PostgreSQL 10.4)
Type "help" for help.

agens=# match (n) return n;
ERROR:  graph_path is NULL
HINT:  Use SET graph_path
```

I want to access graph my own.

Answer (score 0):

You must set "graph_path" before using graph.

To avoid inconvenience, use "alter user ... set graph_path" for binding user to specific graph.

```
$ agens
agens (AgensGraph 2.1.0, based on PostgreSQL 10.4)
Type "help" for help.

agens=# match (n) return n;
ERROR:  graph_path is NULL
HINT:  Use SET graph_path
agens=# set graph_path to graph;
SET
agens=# match (n) return n;
 n 
---
(0 rows)

agens=# alter user agens set graph_path to graph;
ALTER ROLE
agens=# \quit
$ agens
agens (AgensGraph 2.1.0, based on PostgreSQL 10.4)
Type "help" for help.

agens=# match (n) return n;
 n 
---
(0 rows)

agens=#
```